# Nokogiri substituting text between tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to differentiate between plain string texts and valid HTML tags while performing the regex operation.

My initial implementation:

```rb
def html_parser(body, terms:)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
  terms.each do |term|
    doc.xpath('//text()').each do |node|
      dummy = node.add_previous_sibling(Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('dummy', doc))
      dummy.add_previous_sibling(Nokogiri::XML::Text.new(node.to_s.gsub(/\b#{term}\b/, process_term(term)), doc))
      node.remove
      dummy.remove
    end
  end

  doc.at_css('body').children.to_html.gsub('&lt;', '<').gsub('&gt;', '>').gsub('&amp;lt;', '<').gsub('&amp;gt;', '>')
end
```

```rb
html_parser('hello world', terms: ['hello'])
# After performing the operation, the `doc` is wrapping the string inside the `p` tag automatically, which I do not want.
=> '<p>hello world</p>' # this would be some other value, main problem is wrapping with `p` tag.
```

However, this works fine for other valid HTML markups.

```rb
string = '<span>hello world<span>'
html_parser(string, terms: ['hello'])
# works fine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Nokogiri::Document()`, you're asking Nokogiri to create a representation of an HTML document based on what you're passing in. If you're not passing in a full HTML document but, as here, a fragment, Nokogiri wraps your input text into its own template – and if you don't have any outer tags, it will add the `<p>` element. You can see this by calling `#to_s` on the document:

```rb
Nokogiri::HTML('Hello world').to_s

# => <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
"<html><body><p>Hello world</p></body></html>"
```

You could try and faff around trying to find ways to get Nokogiri to use a better template construction, but really I'd say you'll get to what you want faster by one of two approaches:

1. Consider whether using a document fragment (e.g., `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(body)`) would give you what you want. This would probably require larger refactoring of your code, but what you end up with might be neater and more maintainable.
2. You could get a quick win by wrapping your method's `body` input in your own HTML document template, so Nokogiri doesn't do this for you. For example:

```rb
def html_parser(body, terms:)
  html = "<html><body>#{body}</body></html>"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
  # etc.
```

The latter option will fix your issue faster, but the code might not be as neat.